# How to display floating video player atop page view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have a `UIPageViewController` that instantiates three view controllers to swipe between (just like Snapchat). I need to display a floating, draggable view controller that plays videos that minimizes to a video player on the bottom right, where you can swipe left to stop the video (just like YouTube's mini player).

My problem is that I'm able to create the floating, draggable view controller, but the mini player is only visible on whichever view controller it's created from. The video player should be visible from any screen. Also, I can't *only* swipe the mini player to delete it. The `UIPageViewController` swipes along with the mini player.

Here are my options:

In my app delegate, I can return a custom window, where a `UIWindow` is essentially my view controller but always visible, where I'd just create the view programmatically by adding subviews and constraints. I think that I'd be able to only swipe the video player if I wanted to because the `UIWindow` is nested above the `UIPageViewController`:

```
let myWind = CustomWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var window: UIWindow? {
    set {

    }
    get {

        return myWind
    }
}
```

Or, is there a way to nest the floating view controller above the `UIPageViewController` so it's visible on all child view controllers, where I'm able to *only* swipe the mini player left and right to delete it without bringing the `UIPageViewController` with me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple suggestion for you to be able to have some floating content over your UIPageViewController.

- Use a plain UIViewController subclass as a rootViewController to your window.
- Add your UIPageViewController as a childViewController to this view controller using containment apis.
- Add your video view to your main view controller.

That way, you will be able to manage the gestures on your video view and also control your UIPageViewController from a single centralized viewcontroller which ultimately makes your design easier.